# What loss function and metrics should I use to train RNN returning a sequence of categories?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I am trying to train a model returning a class for a sequence of words (RNN).

I feed my model a sequence of embeddings:

> `[ batchSize, sequence_length, word_embedding ] as float[]`

and get back a sequence of one-hot arrays:

> `[ batchSize, sequence_length, number_of_classes ] as bool[]`

which I compare to the ground truth, of the same format.

---

> So, I am wondering:

1. what `loss` should I be using?
2. what `metrics` should I report to keep track of the progress being made?

Comment: Can you share the model making a snippet on stackblitz to have a look at the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you are training a system to perform multiclass classification, where each sample belongs to exactly one of a known set of classes.  For this task, a common choice is to use `categorical_crossentropy` or `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

See here for a defintion of the losses:
https://keras.io/losses/

See here for a basic example of the use (in python, but JS API matches).
https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r2/tutorials/quickstart/beginner.ipynb

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to get confirmation that `categorical_crossentropy` wasn't going to get confused by the fact each of my element in the sequence has its own category, but it seems to work indeed.